# Considering Proxmox to replace individual legacy PCs and LAN servers

Tags: linux, windows, windows-7, windows-xp, proxmox

I have been developing software since the early 1980s and have maintained a number of old PCs for product support of legacy systems. Some have not been turned on in years, but apart from the Z-80 8-bit systems which predate internetworking, there are Windows XP, Windows 2010RS server, Windows 7, and Centos 6 machines on the LAN that I need to get into regularly. (I forgot to add 4 Raspberry Pis running Plex, PiHole, and IOT apps under various flavors of Raspian)

Can a single server running Proxmox be used to host virtualized container environments imaged from these legacy machines so I would not have to maintain such an archaic array of old hardware?